# Web3 - how to add WEI and ETH values correctly

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, blockchain

I'm working on an auction feature in my DApp and having problems correctly adding together two `WEI` values.

The contract stores two important values:
1. A `minBidIncrement` variable - which I've set to `0.1 ETH`, and 
2. A `highestBidAmount` variable - which stores the highest bid anyone has made to date.

Thus, if the last highest bid was say `2.5 ETH`, I want to make sure the next allowable bid would be *at least* that *plus* the `minBidIncrement`, meaning it should be:

`2.5 ETH + 0.1 ETH` which equals `2.6 ETH`.

Its pretty straight forward stuff.

So I'm doing this:

```
    let minNextBid = highestBidAmount + minBidIncrement;
```

but what I get from that is some crazy huge value which causes my Dapp to freak out and Metamask to give me errors.

Here's what's happening underneath the hood:
-`highestBidAmount` comes back as `100000000000000000` 
-`minBidIncrement` also comes back as `100000000000000000`

(both of those are fine cause they're 18 decimal places, which means they're really `0.1 ETH`)

So next when I set my `minNextBid`, I'm basically doing `100000000000000000` + `100000000000000000`, but that yields: `100000000000000000100000000000000000`

And when I then convert that to ETH, I get this value: `100000000000000000.1`

which isn't at all what I was expecting to get. What I was expecting to get was `0.2 ETH`, but I get that astronomical value instead.

So what's happening here? What am I doing wrong?
What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Please show us your actual code. We can't debug nor run your sayings. You never mention it but it looks like a javascript bug to concatenate instead of an addition.

Comment: In case this fixed your problem please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are concatenating strings in JavaScript.

Here is what happens:

```
var test = "he";
var test2 = "llo";
console.log(test+test2);
```

OUTPUTS: `hello`. You are using integers as strings.

Therefore you need to convert your variables to int before adding them.

Here is an example:

```
highestBidAmount = parseInt(highestBidAmount, 10);
```

Sidenote: Don't change the 10 it has nothing to do with decimal places. It's the radix used.

Do that with both variables:

```
minBidIncrement = parseInt(minBidIncrement, 10);
```

Now add them:

```
let minNextBid = highestBidAmount + minBidIncrement;
```

Now you are adding integers so it results in: `200000000000000000`

Comment: That was right on man - I was concatenatin'!  Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#id77), it says

```
Returns:
String|BN: If a string is given it returns a number string, otherwise a BN.js instance.
```

Which means, if you instantiated your wei amount using a string, like this:

```
const amount= web3.utils.toWei("1000","ether")
```

It will return a string value. Now if you try to add two strings together, as the other post mentioned, it will concatenate them. With what you're trying to do, I think you want to instantiate them using a BigNumber, so that it returns a BigNumber. Like so:

```
const amount = web3.utils.toBN("1000");
const amountInWei= web3.utils.toWei(amount ,"ether");
```

You are then able to modify the values using the BN methods. You just need to add `.add .sub .mul` or `.div` dependending on what you want to do.

```
const amountToAdd = web3.utils.toBN("500");
const newAmountInWei = amountInWei.add(amountToAdd);
```

If you want to visualize that value, you can just add .toString() to a BigNumber value to stringify it

```
const stringifiedNewAmountInWei = newAmountInWei.toString();
```